# Nodejs server accepting a PHP cURL

Tags: php, node.js, curl

I have a node server that hosts 3 different apis, then I run separate server for different applications that communicate to the node server. I seem to get undefined/empty string when trying to curl to the node servers. They work fine with posting from a rEST Console or PostMan, which are apps in Google Chrome. But when I try to cURL from a command line or from PHP, it does not work.

I have tried several different things from the cURL call. I am wondering why this won't work. And what can I do on the server end or on my client end to fix it.

Thanks.

EX cURL call:

```
$host = 'http://api.codelabs.io:2403/products';
$json = '{"name":"Wine type 2"}';

$ch = curl_init($host);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 2403);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `HTTPHEADER` , also I commented out the port as it was not neccessary...

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json))
);
```

#### The working code..

```
<?php

$host = 'http://api.codelabs.io:2403/products';
$json = '{"name":"Wine type 2"}';

$ch = curl_init($host);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 2403);   //<----- Commented out !
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(    //<--- Added this code block
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json))
);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($data);
```

**OUTPUT :**

> string 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK Set-Cookie:
>   sid=475e2c66dcb996b2de367f4c626f0d2c3c3a47df4d83ec9fd251560ff1c5e57df1d5d1f6dafb71fd101c5edc065610bd0c5a1bcdb653cdcd6ba23de0677d4864;
>   path=/; httponly Content-Length: 46 Content-Type: application/json
>   Date: Mon, 14 Apr 2014 06:04:05 GMT Connection: keep-alive
>
> {"name":"Wine type 2","id":"0bef0d72a33b2be8"}' (length=342)

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to connect to a local node script with:

```
<?php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json))
);
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$json = '{"   
deviceToken":"975247bb6a1f7362ac34272888b9ae82b571d51ade36c5a18a7235a72de55079","topic":"com.meditation.iPujaPro","badge":"3","sound":"ping.aiff"}';

$ch = curl_init($host);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 3000);   //<----- Commented out !
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(    //<--- Added this code block
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json))
);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($data);
?>
```

but I am receiving: "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"
What's the matter?
If I connect to the server by linx it works seamlessly.

Also if I connect to any other url or port, it works fine, but if I use port 3000 of the listening node js file I get this error.